# Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled Swift 4, SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rest, swifty-json

I'm trying to get consume API REST using NSMutableURLRequest, and to parse json i'm using SwiftyJSON, [Consume Rest API](https://medium.com/@petrosdemetrakopoulos/creating-a-rest-api-manager-in-swift-4cd610699bed) , my code is

```
func getUserLogin(username:String,password:String, onSuccess:@escaping(JSON)-> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error)->Void){
        let url:String = baseURL+APIManager.getUserLogin
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod="POST"
        let postString = "username="+username+"&password="+password
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,completionHandler:{data,response,error->Void in if(error != nil){onFailure(error!)

        }else {
            let result = JSON(data: data!)
            onSuccess(result)
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

but the xcode builder notified me thats there's error in this part

```
let result = JSON(data: data!)
        onSuccess(result)
```

any idea why? because when i try to run example project from [Consume Rest API](https://medium.com/@petrosdemetrakopoulos/creating-a-rest-api-manager-in-swift-4cd610699bed) everything run normall

Comment: What is the error? :D

Comment: try this if let result = JSON(data: data!) { onSuccess(result) } or add the try

Comment: no luck using if and already trying using  do catch still showing error
Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled